# What is an English Wheel and how do I use one?

Tags: fabrication, metal

What exactly is an English Wheel? How can I use one?

Answer (score 7):

An English wheel is a tool for bending flat metal sheets into curved surfaces. (Thanks to @vini-i for a much better, succinct summary!)  As for what *you* can do with one, it's probably about the same as what *I* can do with one which is "not much" at the moment.  :)  But here's a [video of an expert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6GTMAMUee4). Note that this guy makes it look easy, but it's actually embarrassingly easy to really screw up a panel on an English wheel.

This picture should be worth about 1000 words.
[image]

Comment: An English wheel is used to bend flat metal sheets into curved surfaces. This might be more satisfactory of an answer.

Comment: You're right, thanks!  I added your text to the answer.